# How to return the first 4 keys of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to return a sentence where the number of words in the sentence is specified by the integer parameter, size. I tried to loop through the keys using

```
for key in word_positions_dict.keys()
```

and then got stuck after that.

For example:

```
my_dict = {'all': [0], 'animals': [1, 6], 'are': [2, 7], 'equal': [3, 9], 'but': [4], 'some': [5], 'more': [8], 'than': [10], 'others': [11]}
print(build_sentence(my_dict, 4))
```

output should be = all animals are equal

Comment: try this : `print(' '.join(list(my_dict.keys())[:4]))`

Comment: The simplest way is with a slice (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing) as suggested above. If you were to write a loop instead you would need to keep track of how many keys you've seen so far (or "enumerate" the loop), add each new key to a collection (e.g. a list) as you go, and "break" out of the loop once you've collected as many keys as you wanted. You could search for how to do those things.

Answer (score 0):

To create a function like this, you want to convert your `dict_keys` map to a `list`, then slice that list, and finally join the elements with spaces. Would the below work?

```py
def build_sentence(dictionary,size):
  return ' '.join(list(dictionary.keys())[:size])
```

This is essentially a restatement in function form of @l'mahdi's comment to fit the question format, so go upvote their comment.

Here's some useful info:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list